# How come values from my php dont populate in select-option

Tags: php, json, jquery

code to call function:

```
<select id="selectWarrior_1" name="warrior_1"  onclick="return selectWarriors()">
                    <option  selected="selected">----Select----</option>
                </select>
```

code of the function:

```
function selectWarriors() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "display_warriors.php",
            datatype:"json",
            success: function(data) {
                var toAppend = '';
                if(typeof data === "object"){
                    for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
                        var warrior = data[i];
                        toAppend += '<option>'+data[i]['warrior_name']+'</option>';
                    }
                    $("#selectWarrior_1 select").append(toAppend);
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
```

Code of my php:

```
    <?php
header("Content-Type: application/json");

include 'functions/class.php';

$db = new DB();

$result = $db->getWarriors();

$warriors = array();

foreach($result as $names){
    $warriors[] = $names;
}
echo json_encode($warriors);
?>
```

How can I fix this? Why its not populating my select-option i checked my json and it has values.

Comment: return false; <--- check this even on working grounds its returning false

Comment: if you don't mind me asking, why if you are using jQuery would you want to have an "onclick" event anyway?  Wouldn't you prefer to use jQuery to bind the "onchange" event, and then handle the population of the data using $(this) within the return... or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selector is incorrect

Change `$("#selectWarrior_1 select")`

To `$("#selectWarrior_1")`

Answer (score 2):

Forgive the spacing, but I would actually just use jquery and not confuse ourselves with passing between functions (which can cause problems later if you are re-populating content asynchronously).

```
$(function(){
  $('#selectWarrior_1').bind('click',function(){
        if ( $(this).data('warriors-loaded') ) { return; }
        var self = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            url: "display_warriors.php",
            datatype:"json",
            success: function(data) {
              if (! typeof data == 'object') return false;
              $.each(data, function(i,e) {
                self.append( $('<option>' + e['warrior_name'] + '</option>') );
              }
              self.data('warriors-loaded',true);
            }
        });
  });
});
```

Comment: 3 errors: 1: missing parenthesis, 2: every time he clicks on `#selectWarrior_1` the data is appended, 3: you forgot selector in `('#selectWarrior_1')`

Comment: Well deserved, didn't actually test it.  Sorry about the downvote earlier.

Answer (score 1):

Well

input type select has no onclick event. Use onChange or onFocus event instead. Also you dont want to use return while calling the function. In your scenario it seems pretty useless to use `return`. Also watch the selector you  have used.

Comment: Yes, `<select>` can have a "click" event.  Try it yourself: `$('body').append('<select id="select-test">').click(function(){console.log("i am clicked")}).click()`

Comment: Yes correct, sorry my mistake, I never use onclick event on `select` tag. +1 for the correction

Answer (score 0):

You need to treat `data` as a json object:

```
function selectWarriors() {
    $.getJSON('display_warriors.php', function(data) {
        var toAppend = '';
        $.each(data, function(key, val) {
            toAppend += '<option>'+val+'<\/option>';
        });
        $("#selectWarrior_1").append(toAppend);
    });
}
```

Comment: He is already doing that - see `dataType: "json"` in the `$.ajax` method call.

Comment: @FilmJ did you looked at his ajax call ?

Comment: look closer to `for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){` it seems to you he is treating `data` as `json`?

Comment: `json_encode( array( array('name'=>'foo'), array('name'=>'bar') ) )` returns `[{"name":"foo"},{"name":"bar"}]`.

Comment: Are you seeing him making that array? it's just an array with numeric indexes. Please take a closer look at his question and codes and explain the down-vote!

Comment: I apologize, I didn't downvote you as much as I removed the upvote because i felt it was fixing something that wasn't broken - the correct answer WAS indeed the selector... but I was wrong to do it for that reason, so I would rescind - but can't... damn!